# sendmail error only when run as a cronjob

Tags: cron, sendmail

Ubuntu 22.04

This is puzzling me. I have a simple script that emails system status to me from a remote computer. The script runs fine from the command line. But when run as a cronjob, it doesn't work. In case the problem is because cron launches the script as root, I also su'd to root and launched the script from the command line, and no error.

Syslog provides shows these entries:

```
Nov 11 06:00:01 AirchainPC2 CRON[89223]: (kpov_tech) CMD (/home/kpov_tech/Desktop/scripts/sendaudioprocessorstats.sh)
Nov 11 06:00:02 AirchainPC2 cron[89234]: sendmail: recipient address kpov_tech not accepted by the server
Nov 11 06:00:02 AirchainPC2 cron[89234]: sendmail: server message: 553-5.1.3 The recipient address <kpov_tech> is not a valid RFC 5321 address.
Nov 11 06:00:02 AirchainPC2 cron[89234]: sendmail: server message: 553-5.1.3 Please visit
Nov 11 06:00:02 AirchainPC2 cron[89234]: sendmail: server message: 553-5.1.3  https://support.google.com/a/answer/3221692 and review RFC 5321
Nov 11 06:00:02 AirchainPC2 cron[89234]: sendmail: server message: 553 5.1.3 specifications for more information. b12-20020aca220c000000b003ae59076b90sm228694oic.14 - gsmtp
Nov 11 06:00:02 AirchainPC2 cron[89234]: sendmail: could not send mail (account default from /etc/msmtprc)
Nov 11 06:00:02 AirchainPC2 CRON[89221]: (kpov_tech) MAIL (mailed 101 bytes of output but got status 0x0041 from MTA#012)
```

The support link provided in the log output leads me to RFC 5321, an enormously-long technical specification.

How can I debug this? Thank you.

Comment: Uh, I guess you got caught by the common trap: if you login as yourself, then your shell is initiated by whatever is in your .bashrc (or maybe other files). I you call your script from cron, no such initialization is done. You can check by "sudo <yourname>" without the "-" usually used.

Comment: @user535733, Indeed the error suggests that I am using "kpov_tech" as the email address, but I don't. It is my username, but not used in the script. Also, the script runs from command line without error, so that ain't it. 

For Mr. Gearloose's suggestion, I regret that I don't understand what you're offering.

Comment: Here is the line in the script that seems to be associated with the sendmail error: mpack -s "Daily Status Report AirchainPC2" /tmp/current_stats.txt thatjackelliott@kpov.org

Comment: And that string, run at the command prompt runs without error. Used in the .sh it also runs if I run the .sh on the command line. But when when the .sh is run by cron, we see the syslog error messages, above in my OP. Thank you.

Comment: I suspect that the error message is not from `mpack` **within** the script, but is from cron itself trying to send a message **about** the script - which by default will send to the cron user's local mail. Try setting `MAILTO=xxxxxxxxxx@xxxx.org` in your crontab (your email address obfuscated for privacy).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us a minimal example of the script that reproduces the error. We cannot help debug code we can't see. We also need to see the cron line to see how the script is being called.